# intn_t when to use it and when not to

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8 x64 and I'm developing a game from scratch (an engine, if you will). I have multi-platform in mind, including mobile and as I've read through stackoverflow, `ILP`, `LP`, `LLP` might be an issue.
I saw that types like int, long etc. depend very loosely on compiler, machine and who knows on what else and a byte is not exactly 8 bits plus Microsoft has its own extra types -- these are so daunting -- I ask you who know better, to give a hand.

Currently I'm leaning towards `int8_t`, `int16_t` etc. as they look like they fit best these ideas:

1. Guarantees me the type won't overflow on some platform, even mobile, at runtime. Ex: `int x` can hold the value 100000 (int is max 65535 on 16 bit).
2. Assures me I'm using the smallest sized type for the job, not only because memory is a valuable resource but firstly because operations on a larger type is slower. Otherwise I'd have used a 128 bit type (which I'm not sure it exists in C++), as I need relatively good precision for geometry but still I wouldn't trade speed for the precision of some highly specialized math library.

So it follows that I don't need as much control as I need awareness about type sizes, to wisely use all the space and time I can get since games are resource demanding by nature plus I'm working with large data structures (thousands of elements) for rendering.

But `intn_t` might be the wrong way to go exactly because it's fixed and not adapted to individual platform, the CPU of which is optimized for different sized memory blocks.

What's the best suited approach in my case?
When is it advisable to use `intn_t` and when advisable not to?

Comment: "operations on a larger type is slower" is not correct. Operations on non-native words *might* be slower, but generally all operations on all integer types are equally "fast" independent of actual size. Also, using the fixed-size integers doesn't *prevent* overflowing, for example lets say you have an `uint8_t` variable whose value is `255`. Adding `1` to that will overflow. It's easier to know the max values though, but then it's easy anyway using e.g. [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: Assuming all of the platforms you plan to compile on have support for them, the fixed size types are fine.  Worrying about the speed of each type is certainly premature.  If it truly worries you, you could use the int_leastN_t or int_fastN_t types, but you lose the benefit of knowing the size is the same on all platforms, and guessing something will be slow without profiling is just silly.

Comment: I see now about `word`speed. I want to start "properly" so later not to have to refactor.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Aren't numeric limits different per platform/compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just targeting one platform and you're not planning to interop with anything then I wouldn't worry about things.

However, if you want your code to compile on a variety of platforms (OSX, Linux, Windows) then I'd go with the types defined in `cstdint`. Also, if you're planning to interop with other languages that have well defined sizes (eg `int` is 32-bit in Java/C#) then I'd go with the types like `int32_t` as your code will be portable and it's much more explicit what you are doing.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me. I want the code to _run_ on different platforms as "consistently" as possible. No other languages are involved (well, we don't count dll's). Maybe I should `typedef` types and just change them for different platforms. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use fixed size integers, so you prevent overflowing. If it is not available on some platform, the compiler will complain (and a compilation error is much better than a runtime error).

Comment: Can I overwrite types by something like this in my code: `typedef unsigned int uint32_t` etc.? Do I mess something up?

Comment: Why would you do that ? In that case, you wouldn't get any benefit than using normal ints... The C++11 standard has standard types in the *cstdint* file. See http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html and http://www.slideshare.net/adankevich/c11-15621074

Comment: The point is to customize `int` so when the compiler sees `int` is forced to use fixed 32 bit `int32_t` for instance.

Comment: That's very dirty. I wouldn't do that. Why not using int32_t directly ?